# Loop through multiple ifs in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data with multiple status column.

Ex. I have 10 status column,  order should be

1. with 10th status column has values means that value should printed
2. if blank in 10 th status column previous status column should be printed.
3. 9 th status column available that value should be printed.
4. if 9th status column is blank, then 8th previous status should be printed

and so on.

I have tried with following.

=IF(ISBLANK(BZ2),BV2,IF(ISBLANK(BV2),BR2,IF(ISBLANK(BR2),BN2,IF(ISBLANK(BN2),BJ2,IF(ISBLANK(BJ2),BF2,IF(ISBLANK(BF2),BA2,IF(ISBLANK(BA2),AW2,IF(ISBLANK(AW2),AS2,IF(ISBLANK(AS2),AO2,IF(ISBLANK(AO2),AK2,IF(ISBLANK(AK2),AG2,IF(ISBLANK(AG2),AC2,IF(ISBLANK(AC2),Y2,IF(ISBLANK(Y2),U2,))))))))))))))

Is this formula right?

Or any other formula I can use. Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Are the values in these columns text or numbers?

Comment: @BigBen It is in text

Comment: I don't see how your formula above could work. You first test BZ2. If it's blank, you return BV2 without testing whether or not it's blank. You likely want something like: =IF(ISBLANK(BZ2), IF(ISBLANK(BV2), IF(ISBLANK(BR2), BN2, BR2), BV2), BZ2). You will need to add the other columns, of course.

Comment: also remember that a null value resulting from a formula "" or a cell containing just spaces will not return TRUE for the `ISBLANK` function.

Comment: Does your version of Excel support `IFS`?  If it does the formula gets a bit simpler.  `IFS(Staus10<>"", Status10, Status9<>"", Status9, repeat for remaining status',TRUE, Value if no status is non blank)`

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
=INDEX(U2:BZ2,1,MAX(COLUMN(A2:BF2)*(LEN(U2:BZ2)>0)))
```

enter it as an array formula, i.e. pressing Ctrl+Shift+Enter simultaneously.
Assuming your status columns are from U to BZ, as in your example formula.
If not, please change the columns in the formula accordingly.